# MySQL remote access on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: mysql

The followings are commands which I have executed on Ubuntu.

```
$ mysql -u root -p

mysql>GRANT ALL ON my_database.* TO user@'MY_REAL_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';

$ sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

> ```
>  #bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
> ```

```
$ sudo ufw enable

$ sudo ufw allow 3306

$ service mysql restart
```

But when I use another computer on Ubuntu to access mysql on MY_REAL_IP type:

```
$ mysql -u user -p -h MY_REAL_IP
```

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'MY_REAL_IP'

how to fix it? thx

Comment: Please check `telnet <mysql server IP address> 3306` ?

Comment: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
`

Comment: This is the root cause, at first you need to establish network connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `bind-address` should be `0.0.0.0`. If you would like to access this server with real IP address. Or, you can access MySQL with simply localhost.

Would you please change `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, and restart MySQL ?

**EDIT**

It looks there is no network connectivity. Please find the way to connect server with port 3306. [How to make sure that firewall is off?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724792/how-to-make-sure-that-firewall-is-off)

Comment: I turn `#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1` into `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` And the message was same

Answer (score 0):

You may misunderstand the `grand` command, `user@host` means the `user` can login from `host`, which in your case, should be `another computer's ip`, or just use `*` for all ips

Comment: Is that you mean change into like this? `GRANT ALL ON my_database .* TO user@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd'`  And the message was same

Comment: @JonathanCheng Yes, and please make sure your.mysql server is up running and listening port 3306. Lots of reasons could lead to your issue, first of all you should understand every commands or options you are using, e.g. 'bind address'

Answer (score 0):

Exact path on Ubuntu 16.04
**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/my.cnf**
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

```
service mysql restart
```